# Какой должен быть код на сервлете?

Tags: ajax, servlet

Только начала изучать ajax и совсем запуталась( 
Нашла вроде бы неплохой пример - `http://uroki-javascript.ru/tryit.php?filename=tryajax_get_unique` 
Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, ведь в добавок к этому коду должен быть какой-то код на сервлете?

```
<![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// код для IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// код для IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.php?t=" + Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Запросить дату</button>
<p>Кликните кнопку несколько раз, чтобы увидеть, изменяется ли время или возвращается кэшированный файл (в этом случае время будет одно и то же).</p>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
]]>
```

Comment: По сути это тот же запрос к серверу, только "без перезагрузки страницы".

Comment: А можете пояснить, как нужно обрабатывать? Я просто только-только начинаю разбираться с ajax.

Comment: @AnnaReznicova ну у вас java на сервере?

Comment: Да, есть сервлет. Вопрос в том, как из метода doGet(в сервлете) достать параметр, который мы передаем  - Math.random().  Чтобы потом, например, просто вывести его на консоль. Вот этого я не понимаю.

Comment: А, так ajax тут не причем. По сути запрашивается страница с get параметром t. Я, конечно, по java не шарю, но гугл намекает на:

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException {
        String time=req.getParameter("t");
    }